# Redshift has sortkey option when creating a table to improve query performance, does DolphinDB has similar mechanism?

Tags: database, dolphindb

I was an user of Redshift. I'm starting to use DolphinDB recently. I was wondering if DolphinDB has similar mechanism like in Redshift using sortkeys to improve query filtering. If so, what are they?

Comment: What did the manual have to say about that?

Answer (score 1):

Similarly, In DolphinDB, group by partition column will likely increase query performance.